# Is there some way to bruteforce a mathematical function?

Tags: algorithm, brute-force

I'm not sure if this is a stupid question but I couldn't really find anything on Google. Given a few data points for a function f(x) would it be possible to bruteforce what the function f(x) itself might be?

Comment: How many are "a few"?

Comment: Nothing some debugging and disassembling cant crack. But whats the language?

Comment: Say... 30? Even as few as 10? Is there some way to systematically figure out a f(x) that would work for those specific data points?

Comment: I guess this is more of a thought experiment than anything, but say it was server sided, so there would be nothing to play with.

Comment: Yes, you can always find *some* function that generates your sample data. The issue, though, is whether it's the *right* function.

Comment: This question belongs in math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oops I wanted to do this programatically so Stackoverflow came to mind first.

Comment: What @LarryOBrien said. Remember, the real question is: "what does f(x) output when its input is an *unknown* x"? If you only care about the 10  (or 30) inputs, just store them in a hash table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will rely on some prior knowledge of f(x).

If you know that the function is constant, one point is enough; a line, then two points, etc. for polynomial functions.

But if you have no restrictions, this isn't possible.  Assuming function here means something like a real-valued function on the real numbers, there are (uncountably) infinitely many functions which will take the specified values on any finite set of data points.

Answer (score 2):

This is mostly math question. It depends on number of data points that are available. You are basically fitting data to a function. You need two data points for straight line, etc. The commercial solution is TableCurve 2D, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TableCurve_2D. I would search for nonlinear fit on Google.
Fitting algorithms are also described in Numerical Recipes (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_Recipes). The simplest algorithm would look for deviations between assumed function and data points. If you assume certain error on your data points, you can calculate chi-square and goodness of your fit.